# Find the range of $\nu$ such that the inequality $\vert\lambda\vert^2\leq 1$ hold.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Given $$\lambda=-i(\nu \sin(kh))\pm \sqrt{-\nu^2\sin^2(kh)+1},$$
$i=\sqrt{-1}$, $\quad\nu, k,h\in\mathbb{R},\quad\nu\neq 0$, $\quad k>0, \quad h>0$.

If $\vert \lambda\vert^2\leq 1$ what the range of $\nu$?

I assume three cases.

**First case** is $-\nu^2\sin^2(kh)+1> 0$. So I have

\begin{align*}
  \vert\lambda\vert^2 &= \left( \pm \sqrt{-\nu^2\sin^2(kh)+1} \right)^2 + \left( -\nu \sin(kh) \right)^2\\
  &= -\nu^2\sin^2(kh)+1+\nu^2 \sin^2(kh)\\
  &= 1.
 \end{align*}

In this case I can't found the range of $\nu$.

**Second case** is $-\nu^2\sin^2(kh)+1= 0$. So I have
\begin{align*}
  \vert\lambda\vert^2 &= \left( -\nu \sin(kh) \right)^2\\
  &= \nu^2 \sin^2(kh)\\
  &\leq 1.
 \end{align*}

Since $0\leq \sin^2(kh)\leq 1$ then we must have $0\leq \nu\leq 1$.

**Third case** is $-\nu^2\sin^2(kh)+1<0$. So I have
\begin{align*}
  \lambda&=-i(\nu \sin(kh))\pm \sqrt{-\nu^2\sin^2(kh)+1}\\
&= -i(\nu \sin(kh))\pm i\sqrt{\nu^2\sin^2(kh)-1}\\
&= -i\left((\nu \sin(kh))\pm \sqrt{\nu^2\sin^2(kh)-1}\right)\\
 \end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
  \vert\lambda\vert^2 &= \left((\nu \sin(kh))\pm \sqrt{\nu^2\sin^2(kh)-1}\right)^2\\
  &= \nu^2 \sin^2(kh)+ \nu^2\sin^2(kh)-1 \pm 2(\nu \sin(kh)) \sqrt{\nu^2\sin^2(kh)-1}\\
&= 2\nu^2\sin^2(kh)-1 \pm 2(\nu \sin(kh)) \sqrt{\nu^2\sin^2(kh)-1}\\
&= 2\nu^2\sin^2(kh)-1 \pm  2\sqrt{\nu^2\sin^2(kh)(\nu^2\sin^2(kh)-1)}\\
  &\leq 1.\\
\iff &2\nu^2\sin^2(kh)-2 \pm  2\sqrt{\nu^2\sin^2(kh)(\nu^2\sin^2(kh)-1)}\leq 0.\\
\iff &\nu^2\sin^2(kh)- 1\pm  \sqrt{\nu^2\sin^2(kh)(\nu^2\sin^2(kh)-1)}\leq 0.\\
 \end{align*}

In this case, I confused to prove what the range of $\nu$, because the form of $\vert\lambda\vert^2$ is not simple.

**My question:**

How I can get the range of $\nu$ in first case and third case?